# Index of ListView.builder not retained inside listTile onTap while filtering

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I have an issue guys. There is a `listView` I am using to show a list fetched from api. So, I implemented `filtering` function to it, which works well. The issue I have is I discovered that when I tap on a filtered list item, the index value tend to change inside my `listTile onTap` method. How do I retain the original list index structure even after filtering and ensure it works well on tapping.

```
FutureBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    primary: false,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: filteredList.length, 
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                     //index value and structure changes while filtering
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: HexColor("#F5F5F5"),
                              borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(
                                  16.0)),
                          child: ListTile(
                            onTap: () => {
                              showFundModal(index)},
                              //when I tap on a listView item while filtered, the index not correct
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
```

);

Comment: Don't depend on `index` and create `id` in the model itself and use it further.

Comment: how does that work?

Comment: do I pass the index into the id variable in the model?

Comment: Have you tried using keys?

Comment: @Locked how? explain

Comment: Set the key property of the Padding to UniqueKey

Comment: will this return index? what is unique key?

Comment: create a custom model with the data of each card and assign initial index value as `id` for e.g. `{ 'id' : 1, 'title': Card 1'}` and when you apply filter then also id of the model will be same so you can do further manipulation based on id.

Comment: @SanjaySharma I don't really understand. can you share a link?

Comment: or do you want me to post my model class?

Comment: Can you post the code? There is no link. (I don't know if there is). I use this custom logic for filtering and keeping the pointers on the items.

Comment: if i use the id instead of index, how do I fetch the position of the item on the list @SanjaySharma

Comment: you need to maintain two lists, one will contain all items and another will contain filtered items or the items which need to be shown.

Comment: @SanjaySharma I have two lists already for filtered and for allData. The things is how do I get the position for allData list? You know its the filteredList am setting into ListView.Builder

Comment: thanks @SanjaySharma I just fixed my issue based on your suggestions. Many thanks

Comment: Posted as an answer so it will be helpful for others. Please mark and upvote if you find it useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep two list one will contain all the items and one will contain the filtered items or the items to be shown. The data model of the list item should have `id` field that can be used to identify the item and you can use the id to manipulate the data.
You can check following json representation of the list.

```
allData = [
  { 'id' : 0, 'title': Card 1'},
  { 'id' : 1, 'title': Card 2'}
]
```

```
filterdData = [
  { 'id' : 0, 'title': Card 1'},
]
```